# Merging and synonymizing tags: how can we handle tag information?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools, tag-wiki, tag-merge-utility

This is the question about tools accessible to site moderators.

We have several tags that we want to synonymize/merge in some cases. Some tags have tag information, but others don't.

What's the preferable way to gather all these tags and minimize manual work for copy-n-paste tag information for the resulted main tag (new one or already existing)?

Answer (score 2):

There's no special tool to handle tag description merging, hence it's not possible to exclude manual text copying/pasting to the result tag.

In case when resulting tag doesn't exist, or that tag has no description (both short and detailed) you can do the following steps, that don't require manual text copy.

Consider we have tag A with description and want to end with existing tag B:

- **Merge B (as source) to A (destination)**. This step helps us to preserve tag descriptions from A. It will also create tag synonym: B to A.
- **Delete synonym B to A.**
- **Merge A to B.** That will actually rename the tag A to B.

There's special option (in tag merge tool) to change tag synonym direction. Potentially it may replace last two steps, but for unknown reason I just ended with tag B without any description and ability to add it (no link to learn more, top users, synonyms etc).