# Move tag info from source tag to the destination in case when destination tag exists, but doesn't have info yet

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tools, tag-wiki, tag-merge-utility

In tag merging process (available for moderators) when the resulting tag name doesn't exist yet the process will behave like a tag renaming. I.e. all tag info (short and detailed) will be "moved" from the source tag to the newly created tag.

I think it would be very useful to move tag info even in situation when the target tag exists, but doesn't have info at all.

In general, the tag merging process should also takes into account info from the both (source and target) tags to create some combined (manually or automatically) info in result. This will reduce (or even make it not needed) the time to retrieve info from orphaned tag.

Related questions:

- [Merging and synonymizing tags: how can we handle tag information?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391836/339911)
- [No link to orphan tag after tag merging in orphan-wikis page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395176/339911)

Comment: Not automatically, please. Because different sites have different standards. But if you can put them in a queue of sorts... That would work.

Comment: @Mast I think it's not a big problem to fix potential merge conflicts right after the tag merging as a separate step. The main thing is to prevent losing the tag infos, because it's hard/tedious to retrieve it after merging from orphaned tag.

Comment: If we get those merges in a notification box of sorts, it would be workable. Without notifications of any sorts at all, I'd be against this.

Comment: The way to not loose the info in the wiki and excerpt for a merged tag is to think about what you're doing before you do it. In other words, at least copy the information out of wiki and excerpt for the tag you're merging prior to performing the merge. While it would be reasonable for the system to be explicit in the merging process that the information exists and will be lost, this is primarily a training issue, rather than a "let's develop some specific additional UI for something that's both quite rare and *completely covered* by the already existing UI for editing tag wiki and excerpts".

Comment: @Makyen Existing UI is not good enough if you need additionally copy data from several places to some external editor just to paste it as is again to the new tag info. I can't say about your experience, but on the site I moderate I faced with that problem (move tag info to another empty tag) several times in. It's very tedious to do it again and again. Current tag-merging-tool is not suitable for this. Period.